# Node postgres select - how do I access the data returned?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, select

I'm trying to SELECT data from a Postgresql database, using Node.js.  I have been able to return the result, but I'm having trouble accessing the contents of the result.  My query code looks like this:

```
select: function(selection, table, condition, limit,callback)
{
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done)
    {
        let sql;
        let rows = [];
        if(selection === 'ALL')
        {
            sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + table + ' WHERE ' + condition;
        }
        else
        {
            sql = 'SELECT ' + selection + ' FROM ' + table + ' WHERE ' + condition;
        }

        if(isDefined(limit))
        {
            sql = sql + ' LIMIT ' + limit;
        }
        if (err)
        {
            return console.error('Error acquiring client', err.stack);
        }
        if (sql === '')
        {
            console.log("Error: No SQL statement!");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Running query \'" + sql + "\'.");
            client.query(sql,
                function(err, result)
                {
                    if (err)
                    {
                        console.log('Query error: ' + err);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rows = result.rows;
                        callback(rows);
                    }
                });
        }
    });
},
```

The callback passes "rows".  The code where this is picked up looks like this:

```
    let selection = 'prefname';
    let table = 'users';
    let condition = `fbid='${senderID}'`;
    let limit = 1;
    let dbData = [];
    let rowString;
    let greetingText;
    userData.FBUser = uName;
    db.select(selection,table,condition,limit, function(res)
        {
            dbData = res;
            if (!isDefined(dbData))
            {
                console.log("Nothing returned!");
            }
            else
            {
                rowString = JSON.stringify(dbData);
                console.log("Returned: " + rowString);
                for (let key in rowString)
                {
                    if (rowString.hasOwnProperty("prefname"))
                    {
                        console.log("TRUE");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Now, when I run this code, I can see that SOMETHING has been returned from my database.  In my console log, I see this:

```
2018-01-25T17:57:09.465642+00:00 app[web.1]: Running query 'SELECT prefname FROM users WHERE fbid='1769596366406807' LIMIT 1'.
2018-01-25T17:57:09.470727+00:00 app[web.1]: Returned: [{"prefname":"Sam"}]
```

So I know SOMETHING has been returned, but for some reason I cannot get into the JSON string to pull it out.  I've tried using for...in, but it hasn't worked.

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?  Am I even doing it right at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is coming back via the variable `res`.  You then immediately assign a reference to that same data under the name `dbData`.  You take `dbData`, and stringify it into a new variable `rowString`.  Now you use `rowString`, but it's simply a string, not an iterable object.  You need to operate against the `dbData` object to iterate over it's properties, and not `rowString`.

`dbData` looks to be an array of objects, so you'll need to ensure you iterate over it as such.  Could use something like:

```
for(let i = 0; i < dbData.length; i +=1{
  let obj = dbData[i];
  for(let key in obj){
    console.log(`Key: ${key}`);
    console.log(`Value: ${obj[key]}`);
  }
}
```

Untested so just shooting from the hip here, but it'd be something like that...

Comment: OK, well that works.  I assigned "res" (the data from the query) to "dbData" and then when I tried your little iteration, it worked, and outputted the key details to the console.

The reason I was doing the long convoluted thing was because I couldn't figure out how to access the object.

Thanks for the help!